# Where is the pycharm-debug.egg archive on mac found?

Tags: pycharm

I am trying to set up remote debug with pycharm and it looks like there is an option to just add `pycharm-debug.egg archive` to my remote server files but I cannot seem to find the file so that I can include it.

Where can I the `.egg` archive for this on my system. I am under the impression it is installed with the application. But I do not see it in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is directly under the PyCharm installation directory: `/Applications/PyCharm.app/pycharm-debug.egg`

Comment: Thanks I didnt realize one could "reveal" an application folder. I am new to mac osx.

Answer (score 7):

I've just had to find the file, and in PyCharm 5.0.1 it seems to be under:

`/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/debug-eggs/pycharm-debug.egg`